# Keyboard shortcut to enter commonly-used email address

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcuts on Android? I want to enter my commonly-used email address  easily, because most apps require an account.

Comment: Amen, brudda.  I wish this capability were built right in to Android.

Comment: There are apps providing shortcuts for exactly this, take e.g. a look at [Mail Linker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.lamda.maillinker).

Answer (score 1):

What I use is [clipper+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.rojekti.clipper) (free, on the market) which provides snippets for reusable fragments like email addresses. It also stores everything you put on the clipboard, as ditto does on Windows, which is very useful, too.